# Reusing a template in Django by passing different arguments in custom template tags

Tags: python, django, templates, parameters, tags

I trying to create 2 separate views to show parts required and parts produced for an activity/job. The model uses a boolean 'increment' field for filtering True (parts produced) and False (parts required) and to increment/decrement parts from the inventory. I'd like to reuse the same template in Django by passing the increment=True/False through the custom template tags for each button in the activity view. However I keep getting an error `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'addrequired' with keyword arguments '{'id': '1', 'increment': False}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activities/activity/(?P<id>[^/]+)/addrequired$']`

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
...
path('activity/<str:id>/addrequired', add_required_part_to_activity, name='addrequired'),
```

infoActivity.html

```
<div class="col-sm">
            <br>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parts Required</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for required in activitypartsrequired %}
                <tr data-href="{% url 'info_part' required.part.id %}">
                    <td>{{ required.part.partnumber }}</td>
                    <td>{{ required.part.description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ required.quantity }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a href="{% url 'addrequired' id=id increment=False %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-pad" role="button">Add Required Part</a>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Parts Produced</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {% for produced in activitypartsproduced %}
                <tr data-href="{% url 'info_part' required.part.id %}">
                    <td>{{ produced.part.partnumber }}</td>
                    <td>{{ produced.part.description }}</td>
                    <td>{{ produced.quantity }}</td>
                </tr>
                <a href="{% url 'addrequired' id=id increment=True %}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-pad" role="button">Add Produced Part</a>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

views.py

```
def activity_information(request, id):
    activity = get_object_or_404(ActivityModel, id=id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = activity_form(request.POST, instance=activity)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('activities')

    else:
        form = activity_form(instance=activity)
        context = {'activityform': form,
                   'activitypartsrequired': ActivityPartModel.objects.filter(activity=id).filter(increment=False),
                   'activitypartsproduced': ActivityPartModel.objects.filter(activity=id).filter(increment=True),
                   'id': id}
        return render(request, 'infoActivity.html', context)


def add_required_part_to_activity(request, id, increment):
    activity_parts = ActivityPartModel.objects.filter(activity=id).filter(increment=increment)
    parts = PartModel.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = required_part_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('activities')

    else:
        form = required_part_form(initial={'activity': id})
        context = {'requiredpartform': form,
                   'activityrequiredparts': activity_parts,
                   'parts': parts,
                   }
    return render(request, 'addActivityPart.html', context)
```

Am I able to just pass increment=True/False in the custom tags? from what I've read I don't think so. it would be good to reuse the same template and view rather than duplicating them.

Comment: You need to add `increment` as a parameter to your url pattern

Comment: that did it! thankyou.

````
urlpatterns = [
path('activity/<str:id>/addrequired', add_required_part_to_activity, {'increment': False}, name='addrequired'),
    path('activity/<str:id>/addproduced', add_required_part_to_activity, {'increment': True}, name='addproduced'),
````